# Copy with Different Memory Address - Python

Tags: python, class, copy, deep-copy

I made a class object I'll call Node.

I want to make a copy of an instance of this object.  Let's say the original is named "root" and the copy is to be named "start"

If I do 
start = root.

When I make any changes to start, it also changes root.  This is because they share a memory address.

How can I make start = root with different memory address?

I tried messing around with copy/deepcopy after some searching but it tells me there is no such attribute.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem using deepcopy from the lib copy. In my case I had other objects within the object I wanted to duplicate, so I had to use deepcopy otherwise just copy would have solved the problem. 
Take a look at the lib's documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Remember:

```
import copy
start = copy.deepcopy(root)
```